# How to get the month and year from a list

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of dates, and I want to run a script in order to hide past months with the script, for that script I just need to set a "1" on the next column and automatically hides the rows

The question is how to get "1" only in the past months from this table?

Here is a demo sheet for reference

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v1fZ_B5veeKaMRgk_JbT3Ds-KqdIo447ywAH82xEafE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this array formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A), IF(TODAY()>EOMONTH(A3:A, 0) , 1, ), ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Merely to show `1` a script seems excessive (and if really required SO expects some effort in writing such a script to be shown) but a formula might suit:

```
=if(today()>eomonth(A3,),1,"")
```

copied down.